# How to make 3-corner-rounded triangle in CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'd like to achieve a custom-colored shape like this using no Javascript:
[image: 3 corner rounded triangle]

Currently I'm overlaying an image of the 'frame' over an orange rectangular div, but this is pretty hacky.
I suppose I could use a dynamically generated canvas element, but that not only requires JS, but HTML5 canvas support. Any ideas?

Comment: +1 Interesting challenge! Yeah, you can do it using just CSS. I'll make a demo :)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

My best attempt: http://dabblet.com/gist/4592062
[image: final]

Pixel perfection at any size, uses simpler math than Ana's original solution, and is more intuitive in my opinion :)

```css
.triangle {
 position: relative;
 background-color: orange;
 text-align: left;
}
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background-color: inherit;
}
.triangle,
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
 width:  10em;
 height: 10em;
 border-top-right-radius: 30%;
}

.triangle {
 transform: rotate(-60deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866);
}
.triangle:before {
 transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414,.707) translate(0,-50%);
}
.triangle:after {
 transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707,1.414) translate(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: How about an isosceles triangle, pointing left? Being the right side the largest.

Comment: Thanks much for this - I'm using it in a site of mine now.  Just a heads up for future readers: if you use 'vmin' for sizing, it can end up looking a little skewed depending on the resulting px values.  Not sure why, because if you manually type in those same px values, the triangle looks fine.  Hopefully near-future browsers will render this comment obsolete!

Comment: It's a great solution! For some browsers at some triangle sizes, I found I needed more digits of sqrt(2) and sqrt(2)/2, though, to get a perfect image.

Comment: Great solution, note that need to `direction:ltr` for rtl pages.

Comment: Looks great. Do you know how I can make the one pointing to the right? And also, how to stretch it a little bit width-wise?

Comment: Great solution, perfection would be fitting a background image in it :)

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic Change  `rotate(-60deg)` to `rotate(-30deg)` and it will point to the right

Comment: If the transparency of the color is low, the color will appear strange. Is there any solution?

Comment: @Sh031224 could you use the full alpha color and then just reduce the opacity of the parent `.triangle`?

Answer (score 34):

```css
.triangle, .triangle:before, .triangle:after { width: 4em; height: 4em; }
.triangle {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 7em auto 0;
    border-radius: 20%;
    transform: translateY(50%) rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg) scaleX(.866);
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: none;
} 
.triangle:before, .triangle:after {
    position: absolute;
    background: orange;
    pointer-events: auto;
    content: '';
}
.triangle:before {
    border-radius: 20% 20% 20% 53%;
    transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translateY(-42.3%) 
            skewX(30deg) scaleY(.866) translateX(-24%);
}
.triangle:after {
    border-radius: 20% 20% 53% 20%;
    transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translateY(-42.3%) 
            skewX(-30deg) scaleY(.866) translateX(24%);
}

/** extra styles to show how it works **/

.triangle:hover { overflow: visible; }
.triangle:hover:before, .triangle:hover:after { background: none; }
.triangle:hover, .triangle:hover:before, .triangle:hover:after {
    border: dashed 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class='triangle'></div>
```

The idea is really simple: you first apply a series of transforms to your `.triangle` element (which has `overflow: hidden;` - you can remove that to see what happens ;) ) in order to get a rhombus.

Then you apply the same transforms to the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, plus a few more to make them rhomboidal as well.

And in the end, you have three rhombuses which intersect, the orange shape being their intersection. Hover the triangle to see the intersecting shapes ;)

It scales nicely, you just have to change the `width` and the `height` of the `.triangle` element.

For Firefox, Chrome and Safari, only the orange triangle with rounded corners is sensitive to hover (thanks to `pointer-events: none;` on the `.triangle` element and `pointer-events: auto;` on the pseudo-elements). Otherwise, this could be achieved by wrapping `.triangle` in an element having the same `width` and `height` (and the same `border-radius`) and `overflow: hidden;`.

---

#### Notes

- You could also do it with CSS gradients. However, [unlike 2D
  transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), CSS gradients [won't work in IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients).
- I'd wish I didn't have to unskew the pseudo-elemets which inherit the skew from their parent only to skew them again after a rotation, but it doesn't seem to work otherwise.

Comment: The only issue is, at very large sizes and/or on  certain screens, there are minor imperfections at both bottom corners; a result of the approximated radii, no doubt

Comment: We miss you, @Ana ! That's a beautiful solution

Comment: @Ana +1 Amazing!, but...how do you calculate the values for scale skew and rotate? Do you have a blog somewhere explaining this?

Answer (score 20):

**New answer**

I have made an online generator where you can find a few triangle with rounded corners made using only CSS: https://css-generators.com/triangle-shapes/

It works with any kind of element and you can easily adjust the radius using a CSS variable

```css
.triangle {
  --r:20px; /* border radius */

  width: 300px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/cos(30deg);
  --_g:calc(tan(60deg)*var(--r)) bottom var(--r),#000 98%,#0000 101%;
  -webkit-mask:
    conic-gradient(from -30deg at 50% calc(200% - 3*var(--r)/2),#000 60deg,#0000 0)
     0 100%/100% calc(100% - 3*var(--r)/2) no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(var(--r) at 50% calc(2*var(--r)),#000 98%,#0000 101%),
    radial-gradient(var(--r) at left  var(--_g)),
    radial-gradient(var(--r) at right var(--_g));
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
  object-fit: cover;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#FA6900,#C02942);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/177/400/400" alt="a random traveler" class="triangle">

<div class="triangle" style="--r:30px;"></div>
```

[image: CSS triangle shapes]

You can also have some animation, check this: https://css-tip.com/triangle-rounded-corner/

---

**Old Answer**

First we create the triangle using `clip-path`:

```css
.triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  color:orange;
}

.triangle::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 86%;
  background: currentColor;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

And then we apply and SVG filter inspired from [this article](https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/)

```css
.triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  color:orange;
  filter: url('#goo');
}

.triangle::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 86%;
  background: currentColor;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="triangle" style="color:red;width:200px;"></div>
<div class="triangle" style="color:blue;width:250px;"></div>


<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

[image: CSS rounded triangle]

To control the radius, we simply adjust the `stdDeviation` of the filter

---

Considering this, you can make it working with any kind of triangle and even a random shape:

```css
.triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  color:orange;
  filter: url('#goo');
}

.triangle::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 86%;
  background: currentColor;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.triangle.type2::before {
  padding-top: 70%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.triangle.type3::before {
  padding-top: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 80% 100%, 0 70%);
}

.triangle.hex::before {
  padding-top: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="triangle type2" style="color:red;"></div>
<div class="triangle type3" style="color:blue;"></div>
<div class="triangle hex" style="color:purple;"></div>



<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

[image: CSS rounded corner shapes]

Worth to note that we can easily add complex background to the shapes:

```css
.triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  filter: url('#goo');
}

.triangle::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 86%;
  background: var(--b,orange);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.triangle.type2::before {
  padding-top: 70%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.triangle.type3::before {
  padding-top: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 80% 100%, 0 70%);
}

.triangle.hex::before {
  padding-top: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="triangle type2" style="--b:linear-gradient(red,blue);"></div>
<div class="triangle type3" style="--b:conic-gradient(green,pink,green);"></div>
<div class="triangle hex" style="--b:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1067/200/200) center/cover;"></div>



<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

[image: Rounded shape with CSS gradient]

Comment: This is a great solution but it doesn't support transparent or semi-transparent background. Am I wrong?

Comment: @kratess you can always add opacity to the main element

Answer (score 12):

Use an image of some sort. That's what images are for. If you need it to scale, [SVG is a good choice](http://jsfiddle.net/ZA8ea/), otherwise, just use a png as a background, or an `<img>` element if it's part of content.

If you absolutely *must* have it in a CSS file, you could try [data: urls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (not supported in IE7 and below).

Comment: Though `<span class="triangle"></span>` is probably easier to remember than `<path d="M 24 4 L 43 37 L 5 37 z" />` :)

Comment: @jinglesthula, `<img src="triangle.svg" alt="triangle">` isn't hard to remember at all, and has the advantage of actually being accessible.

Answer (score 6):

Ana's answer inspired me to try another approach, one that's just as far from perfect, but is at least symmetrical. Here's a preview at real-size and blown up. It's simply a border-hack trangle wrapped in a clipping circle/border-radius:

[image: Preview]

And the code (adjust the overall size via single `font-size` property):

```
.triangle {
    font-size: .8em;
    position: relative;
    width: 3.8em;
    height: 3.8em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10% auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100%;
} 
.triangle:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border: solid 2em transparent;
    border-bottom-color: orange;
    border-bottom-width: 3.2em;
    border-top-width: 0;
    margin: -.3em -2em;
}
```

Play with it here: http://dabblet.com/gist/4590714

Comment: Amazing! because the :after is available to use for the exclamation mark ! to make a warning icon !

Answer (score 3):

Played around with Murray Smiths most upvoted version. Wrote it as a Stylus mixin and fixed some margin issues and added a direction option. The mixin also scales the triangle to somewhat pixelperfect size. Not tested very well. Use with care

http://codepen.io/perlundgren/pen/VYGdwX

```
    triangle(direction = up, color = #333, size = 32px)
        position: relative
        background-color: color
        width:  2*(round(size/3.25))
        height: 2*(round(size/3.25))
        border-top-right-radius: 30%
        &:before,
        &:after
          content: ''
          position: absolute
          background-color: inherit
          width:  2*(round(size/3.25))
          height: 2*(round(size/3.25))
          border-top-right-radius: 30%

        if direction is up
          transform: rotate(-60deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866)
          margin: (@width/4) (@width/2.5) (@width/1.2) (@width/2.5)

        if direction is down
          transform: rotate(-120deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866)
          margin: 0 (@width/1.5) (@width/1.5) (@width/6)

        if direction is left
          transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866)
          margin: (@width/5) 0 (@width) (@width/1.4)

        if direction is right
          transform: rotate(-90deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866)
          margin: (@width/5) (@width/1.4) (@width) 0

        &:before
          transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414,.707) translate(0,-50%)
        &:after
          transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707,1.414) translate(50%)
```

and then just add the mixin to your class

```
    .triangle
      &.up
        triangle()
      &.down
        triangle(down)
      &.left
        triangle(left)
      &.right
        triangle(right)
```

Answer (score 2):

-- Simplified version --

In my case I needed text to accompany the triangle icon with three rounded corners, however the `overflow: hidden;` suggested simply did not work because the text was ultimately rendered hidden.

End Result: [image: The word "Mandatory" along with a triangular warning icon]
...Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/allenski/7p4tbznr/

I was able to achieve similar mask by using `clip-path`. Note: does not work in IE; however most already stopped supporting IE, especially since Microsoft did. Works great in their new Edge browser.

HTML:

```
<span class="warning">
    Mandatory
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.warning {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FF5500;
}
.warning:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 12px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transform: translateY(-36%);
    text-shadow: 0 0 7px #111111;
    z-index: 1;
    content: '!';
}
.warning:after {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 3px;
    font-size: 5px;
    border: solid 3em transparent;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 5em;
    border-bottom-color: #FF5500;
    clip-path: circle(54% at 50% 69%);
    vertical-align: bottom;
    content: '';
}
```

In the CSS, the triangle is the `:after` pseudo-element.

Comment: The goal in my case was to also contain these elements within one HTML tag, therefore the triangle could only be the `:before` or `:after`

Answer (score 1):

I saw there was someone asking for an isosceles triangle and through some tampering with the accepted answer above I found how to manipulate it to get what I wanted considering I needed the same. This should help anyone looking for a slight change in the rounded corner triangle.

You'll notice that I separated out the width, height, and border-top-right-radius then proceeded to change the border-top-right-radius to shape the corners. The only other thing I changed was the transform property on the element directly. You can shape it how you see fit, but those seem to be the only necessary changes.

```css
.diff-arrow {
  margin-left:30px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #20C0F1;
  text-align: left;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border-top-right-radius: 20%;
}

.diff-arrow:before,
.diff-arrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border-top-right-radius: 15%;
}

.diff-arrow {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) skewX(0deg) scale(0.5);
}

.diff-arrow:before {
  transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414, .707) translate(0, -50%);
}

.diff-arrow:after {
  transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707, 1.414) translate(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="diff-arrow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As we are in 2024 now, we can use one liner code to get the triangle with round corners. I have used triangle font from https://fontawesome.com/

You can easily register with fontawesome and use all free font icons with your website. As the triangle drawn is a font, you can style it as you style your fonts in CSS.

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a611f40df6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
.triangle{
  font-size:50px;
  color: blue;
}
.triangle-2{
  font-size:50px;
  color: red;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</style>
<i class="fa-solid fa-play triangle"></i>
<i class="fa-solid fa-play triangle-2"></i>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.triangle {
    position: relative;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: left;
}
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: inherit;
}
.triangle,
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
    width:  10em;
    height: 10em;
    border-top-right-radius: 30%;
}

.triangle {
    transform: rotate(-60deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866);
}
.triangle:before {
    transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414,.707) translate(0,-50%);
}
.triangle:after {
    transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707,1.414) translate(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Started with the typical border triangle and then added svg filter to the triangle.

```css
.c-paper-plane {
    position: relative;
}
.scene {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotate3d(0.2, -1, -0.8, -177deg);
}
svg.paper-plane {
    transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(-3px);
    transform-origin: center;
}
.paper-tail {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(31px, 10px) translateZ(-5px);
    transform-origin: center;
    fill: grey;
}
.paper-tail-div {
    transform: rotateX(269deg) translate(237px, 55px) translateZ(139px);
    fill: grey;
    transform-origin: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 150px solid transparent;
    filter: url('#goo');
}
```

```html
<div class="c-paper-plane">
  <div class="scene">
    <svg id="paper-plane" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 139.549 79.269">
                <defs>
                    <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
                        <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
                        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
                    </filter>
                </defs>
                <g class="plane-group">
                    <path class="paper-wing" d="M47.377,76.654V47.025c0-1.137,0.871-2.084,2.003-2.178l60.357-5.062c0.2-0.01,0.2-0.29,0-0.31l-60.356-5.052
                    c-1.133-0.095-2.004-1.042-2.004-2.179V2.615c0-1.878,1.922-3.142,3.646-2.399l87.37,37.662c1.54,0.664,1.54,2.848,0,3.512
                    l-87.37,37.662C49.299,79.796,47.377,78.531,47.377,76.654z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
    <div class="paper-tail-div"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```