# Image inside triangle css?

Tags: css, user-interface

I'd like to achieve a custom image triangle shape with rounded corner like this using `css`

[image]

I looking for how achieve like this but nothing, 
i want to achieve my `css` can do result like this,any ideas?
Sorry if my question has looks like other question

Thanks

Comment: Do you mind if the end result utilses a png? Or do you literally want a pure css solution here?

Comment: You should probably use a png as Sean suggests. However if you really want to do it with css only [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446677/how-to-make-3-corner-rounded-triangle-in-css) might help you out.

Comment: @SeanDunwoody : yes,i want make it pure css only and the image as a background.similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446677/how-to-make-3-corner-rounded-triangle-in-css..but i want the backgroun is png..please help..I've been search long time  to achieve like that,,

Answer (score 1):

You could use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path). It allows you to show only part of an element and hide the rest, so make a polygon with sufficient dots for the rounded effect at corners.

```css
.tri {

    position: relative;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    background: url("http://pdphoto.org/images/tacos.jpg");

    clip-path: polygon(1% 78%, 46% 2%, 49% 0, 54% 0, 57% 2%, 98% 78%, 98% 83%, 95% 87%, 89% 88%, 6% 89%, 2% 87%, 0 83%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="tri"></div>
```