# How to round out corners when using CSS clip-path

Tags: css, css-shapes, clip-path

I want to be able to round out the 3 leftmost corners on this shape that I have created, any idea how that can be done?

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 423px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #b0102d;
  color: white;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 10vw;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%, 25% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%, 25% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: yeah thats what I used to make the shape but i just don't know how to round the corners. Any ideas?

Comment: You'd have to go the SVG clip path route I suspect. I don't think `polygon` supports curves. - http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/

Comment: hmmm i see. Alright thanks for the link

Comment: @Paulie_D is correct. CSS only `clip-path` supports only basic shapes (like polygon, circle). It does not support a combination of shapes or paths and you would have to use SVG (inline or external) for that.

Comment: for later readers, replying to the question in title: notice in Clippy you have the rounded border option in `inset()`: `clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0 round 10%);`

Comment: @antoni but how can apply it to polygon?

Comment: @A.Anvarbekov, unlike inset which includes the option to round, I don't think it's possible to round angles of a polygon inside a clip-path. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape/polygon But I would do it in SVG where you can draw a path with curve linking points, try this excellent tool: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

Answer (score 34):

use inset with round property :

```
inset(0% 45% 0% 45% round 10px)
```

Comment: Can you dig this a little dipper? I really don't understand how can I round the corners with inset with this kind of shape

Comment: perfect. elegant. exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Mehrshad Cheshm Khavari for use of clip-path: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_clip-path.php

Yes you can just round a div, but in some cases if you need to use the clip-path: inset that was my solution make the border round

Answer (score 16):

An SVG filter can round any kind of `clip-path`. You simply need to apply it to a parent element. Adjust the `stdDeviation` to control the radius:

```css
.box {
  width: 423px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #b0102d;
  color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%, 25% 0%);
}

.parent {
  filter: url('#goo');
  overflow:hidden;
  position: fixed;
  right:-50px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65485455/8620333

Comment: This works well for me in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Are there any solutions for this?

Comment: nice, what if that shape has different color of border, how can we add border?

Answer (score 10):

I've recently found success experimenting with approaches like this...

SVG

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipped">
      <circle cx="var(--myRad)" cy="var(--myRad)" r="var(--myRad)"></circle>
      <circle cx="var(--myRad)" cy="calc(var(--myHeight) - var(--myRad))" r="var(--myRad)"></circle>
      <circle cx="calc(var(--myWidth) - var(--myRad))" cy="calc(var(--myHeight) - var(--myRad))" r="var(--myRad)"></circle>
      <circle cx="calc(var(--myWidth) - var(--myRad))" cy="var(--myRad)" r="var(--myRad)"></circle>
      <rect y="var(--myRad)" width="var(--myWidth)" height="calc(var(--myHeight) - (2 * var(--myRad)))"></rect>
      <rect x="var(--myRad)" width="calc(var(--myWidth) - (2 * var(--myRad)))" height="var(--myHeight)"></rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
.clipped {
  --myWidth: 100vw;
  --myHeight: 10rem;
  --myRad: 2rem;
  clip-path: url(#clipped);
}
```

I found this useful as compared to using border-radius with overflow set to hidden, because this approach doesn't create a BFC or break things like sticky position and css perspective effects. Also, this allows you to "inset" the position of the svg paths to clip inside the element with a "corner-radius" if you want.

Comment: Can you post a pen?

Comment: @ElvioCavalcante not completely reduced, but try it in a chromium browser, and add prefixed properties for others, you can see how values are derived between this fiddle and my original answers example. http://jsfiddle.net/y7heo6md/1/

Comment: For folks who missed the comment by @antoni above, my answer here is effectively doing the same thing as using the inset() method with the round option. Like clip-path: inset(0 round 2rem), but keep in mind the round option hasn't always been supported by browsers, so progressively enhance or just use this SVG approach for compat.

Comment: So can you not use var/calc for SVG dimensions? The jsfiddle you posted you converted everything to pixels, and I can't get an example to work based on what you posted here.

Answer (score 9):

You can also mess around with the circle to get some different effects.

```
-webkit-clip-path: circle(60.0% at 50% 10%);
clip-path: circle(50.0% at 50% 50%);
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/J-Roel/pen/VmEpvq)

Too bad you can't combine the polygon and circle... or maybe you can and I haven't played around with it enough to figure it out. HTH

Answer (score 7):

clip-path: inset(45% 0% 33% 10% round 10px)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a comment option yes, so I'm writing it as an answer..

you need to write as many points as possible to round the corner. Nothig else...
for, example a few more points to make lower part bit rounder:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 5% 70%,1% 60%, 0% 50%, 25% 0%);
```

oh, yes, or SVG as comment people here.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a child element and do a nested `clip-path` on that and the child's pseudo element. The parent will do a `polygon` clip on the shape first, then the pseudo will have an `ellipse` to round the borders. The clips will have a combined effect.

```css
.parent, .parent div, .parent div:before {
  width: 423px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
}

.parent {
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 210px, #b0102d 210px);
  margin-top: 15vh;
}

.parent div {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
}

.parent div:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #b0102d;
  clip-path: ellipse(200px 45px at 210px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Here is the demo with some adaptations to illustrate what's going on:

```css
.parent, .parent div, .parent div:before {
  width: 423px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
}

.parent {
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 210px, yellow 210px);
  margin-top: 15vh;
}

.parent div {
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(90% 0%, 90% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
}

.parent div:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #b0102d;
  clip-path: ellipse(200px 45px at 210px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

The horizontal size and position of the ellipse can be used to get a different effect on the edges. Note that the background starting postion of the parent needs to be adjusted to the same value as the placement of the ellipse (last value in the `clip-path`) because it fills up whatever gets clipped off on the right side. This can be visualised by removing `background-color: blue` from `.parent div` in the second demo.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/drXmbp?editors=1100) is an additional Codepen to to try it out.