# Setting only two rounded corners of a button in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

Is it possible to set only two rounded corners of a button in nativescript ? I am not sure if specifying radius as a css property would work, since radius rounds all the four corners, while I can't seem to find a semi circle or semi-ellipse in clip path.

Answer (score 0):

Currently NativeScript supports uniform border-radius only. You can try to set a polygon clip path. Here is an example of a polygon clip path that clips a star:

```
<Button text="polygon" style="background-color: magenta; border-width:2; border-color: red; clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 0% 20%, 30% 50%, 0% 80%, 20% 100%, 50% 70%, 80% 100%, 100% 80%, 70% 50%, 100% 20%, 80% 0%, 50% 30%);" row="3" />
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765345/how-to-round-out-corners-when-using-css-clip-path) might help you with rounding the corners with a clip path.

Comment: Check that out:
  https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/2102

Answer (score 0):

You can use also this tool to generate clip-paths:
http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like a chat bubble so I wrapped rounded labels inside a container -like stacklayout- and set the left/right-margins  off the container.