# How to keep border-radius when using clip-path?

Tags: css, clip-path, border-radius

I have a project where I need to create a certain type of card. These cards contain a gradient background when hovered over. I have added a before item that is shown when the item is hovered over. In order to contain the background gradient within the card I have added a clip path attribute to the card.

But the problem I am facing is that the clip path doesn't clip the rounded border `border-radius: 0.5rem;`. I have searched and found that it is possible by using a polygon to clip path.

I have found a link where you can generate poly items to clip to: [Clip poly generator](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).

But i cannot find a perfect polygon that fits. The circle is to rounded and the bevel item only has sharp borders.

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
  }

.card-oval-gradient {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 6rem;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

.card-oval-gradient > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.card-oval-gradient:hover::before {
  content: '';

  position: absolute;
  left: -7rem;
  top: -10rem;
  width: 18rem;
  height: 28rem;
  -moz-border-radius: 15rem / 20rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15rem / 20rem;
  border-radius: 15rem / 20rem;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(61deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    138deg,
    #4d3d8f 0%,
    #df67ed 23%,
    #e24c26 65%,
    #f18823 84%,
    #3aa6c2 100%
  );

  filter: blur(50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-oval-gradient">
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765345/how-to-round-out-corners-when-using-css-clip-path

Comment: @AnthonyBeaumecker I have read this question. But I couldn't get it to work for my example.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need a clip path at all. Do you have an image of the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mask not clip-path:

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
  }

.card-oval-gradient {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 6rem;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
}

.card-oval-gradient > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.card-oval-gradient:hover::before {
  content: '';

  position: absolute;
  left: -7rem;
  top: -10rem;
  width: 18rem;
  height: 28rem;
  -moz-border-radius: 15rem / 20rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15rem / 20rem;
  border-radius: 15rem / 20rem;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(61deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    138deg,
    #4d3d8f 0%,
    #df67ed 23%,
    #e24c26 65%,
    #f18823 84%,
    #3aa6c2 100%
  );

  filter: blur(50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-oval-gradient">
</div>
```