# rounded corners and border for clip path at the same time

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs, clip-path

[image]
Hello,
I'm trying to build the breadcrumb shown in the picture I've reviewed tons of solutions for the breadcrumbs but none of them could make rounded corners, so I decided to use clip-paths.

here is my code now :

```css
.box {
      width: 425px;
      height: 90px;
      background-color: #dfdfdf;
      color: white;
      clip-path: polygon(90% 10%, 100% 50%, 90% 90%, 0% 90%, 10% 50%, 0% 10%);
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

I've tried to use methods from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765345/how-to-round-out-corners-when-using-css-clip-path) but in this case, when we combine two paths for creating border, rounded corner maker SVG does not apply to the inner one. if we nest them in order to apply SVG to the inner one they don't fit.

any ideas to achieve this?

Comment: from the linked question did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504085/8620333 ?

Comment: Haven't you asked this a few days ago already?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, still no success. as I said in the question they don't fit

Comment: @prettyInPink yes but it was a totally different approach with pseudo-elements I thought it may be confusing to write this after previous approach so i decided to create new question instead of making previous one hard to understand

Comment: This time i have came up with new idea of *skew*, (**edit 3**),please see again my answer

Answer (score 4):

### Great question , And a answer that *fits* properly

This answer is for the case you said

> they don't fit.

And so it **fits properly**

### New Answer

```css
:root {
  --break: 0.3333333333em;
  --textColor: #4285f4;
  --bg: #eee;
  --deegree: 20deg;
  --borderRadius: 5px;
  --BorderColor: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  --BorderThick: 2px;
  --width: 75%;
  --height: 20px;
}
.centerer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.multi-step-list {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: var(--width);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.multi-step-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 var(--break);
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius);
}

.multi-step-item .item-title {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.multi-step-item .item-title {
  color: var(--textColor);
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.item-wrap {
  padding: calc(var(--height) / 2);
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.item-wrap:before,
.item-wrap:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: var(--bg);
}
.item-wrap:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: skew(var(--deegree));
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius) var(--borderRadius) 0 0;
  border-color: var(--BorderColor);
  border-width: var(--BorderThick);
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
.item-wrap:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: skew(calc(0deg - var(--deegree)));
  border-radius: 0 0 var(--borderRadius) var(--borderRadius);
  border-color: var(--BorderColor);
  border-width: var(--BorderThick);
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerer">

  <div class="multi-step">
    <ul class="multi-step-list">
      <li class="multi-step-item">
        <div class="item-wrap">
          <p class="item-title">Step One</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="multi-step-item">
        <div class="item-wrap">
          <p class="item-title">Step Two</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="multi-step-item">
        <div class="item-wrap">
          <p class="item-title">Step Three</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="multi-step-item">
        <div class="item-wrap">
          <p class="item-title">Step Four</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Idea

[image]

- As shown above we dive rectangle into two parts,give border radius...,**and skew the rectangle**,the result is got finally

## Sorry posting here in stackoverflow don't run well(smoothly),try the pen below

#### [A pen](https://codepen.io/neptotech/full/ExbNWry)

---

### Old Answer

```css
:root {
    --radius: 15px;
  --radius2: 15px;/*Edit:2*/
    --OuterRadius: 15px;
    --height: 120px;
    --bg: #ddd;
    --borderBg: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    --textColor: #666;
    --thick: 1px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.breadcrumb {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: var(--OuterRadius);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--height);
    background-color: var(--bg);
    font-size: 14px;
}

.breadcrumb .h {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 38px;
    padding-right: 0;
    color: var(--textColor);
}

.breadcrumb .h:first-child {
    padding-left: 15.2px;
}

.breadcrumb .h:last-child {
    padding-right: 15.2px;
}

.breadcrumb .h:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(var(--height) + var(--thick));
    height: calc(var(--height) + var(--thick));
    top: calc(0px - (var(--thick) / 2));
    right: calc(0px - (var(--height) / 2));
    background-color: var(--bg);
    border-top-right-radius: var(--radius);
  border-top-left-radius: var(--radius2);
  border-bottom-right-radius: var(--radius2);
    transform: scale(0.75) rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: var(--thick) calc(0px - var(--thick)) var(--borderBg);
    z-index: 1;
}

.breadcrumb .h:last-child:after {
    content: none;
}

.breadcrumb__inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 2;
}

.breadcrumb__title {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*responsive*/

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .breadcrumb {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 710px) {
    :root {
        --radius: 15px;
        --OuterRadius: 15px;
        --height: 70px;
    }
    .breadcrumb__desc {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="breadcrumb">
        <div class="h">
            <span class="breadcrumb__inner">
                <span class="breadcrumb__title">Website Root</span>
                <span class="breadcrumb__desc">First Item</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="h">
            <span class="breadcrumb__inner">
                <span class="breadcrumb__title">Page Depth 02</span>
                <span class="breadcrumb__desc">Second Item</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="h">
            <span class="breadcrumb__inner">
                <span class="breadcrumb__title">Page Depth 03</span>
                <span class="breadcrumb__desc">Third Item</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="h">
            <span class="breadcrumb__inner">
                <span class="breadcrumb__title">Page Depth 04</span>
                <span class="breadcrumb__desc">Fourth Item</span>
                <span class="breadcrumb__desc">With Additional Line</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="h">
            <span class="breadcrumb__inner">
                <span class="breadcrumb__title">Page Depth 05</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## [**This is my pen**](https://codepen.io/neptotech/full/YzEGBqj) & [*I got idea from here*](https://codepen.io/iamglynnsmith/full/BRGjgW)

### Idea

- Use the `:after` as an object, give it a *border-radius*, **Tilt/rotate it to form the arrow**
- Clip the arrow, and do other stuff, like border-color...

#### Features

- *Responsive*
- *Automatic*
- Use of CSS *`variables`*

##### Available variables

- radius
- OuterRadius
- height
- bg
- borderBg
- textColor
- thick
- degree

> Tip: You may try the same idea of `rotating` the `:after` element for just a single item

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, but there is a problem: if we count corners clockwise from the top-left corner we would have 6 of them by considering middle items, in your code, we don't have any rounded corner on point numbers 1, 2, 4, 5 and in the picture we have rounded corner on all of them, for better understanding of my idea please see this image: https://ibb.co/vBtpLx6

Comment: @NamiPoorsafargholi i have edited answer for those radius too ,try again

Comment: @NamiPoorsafargholi This time i have came up with new idea of *skew*, (**edit 3**),please see again my answer