# CSS L rounded shaped div with gradient background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an L shaped div in css and it have a couple things that I cant figure out.

I want it to have rounded edges, be clickable inside the div but not inside missing edge (not sure if this is possible)

I made a version in svg using a tool but I realized it wont scale as I need it to and it needs to be CSS conditional rather than html conditional.

[image]

I found an example here of an L div
But I cant get the inside edges to curve and or apply an inside div gradient background to it:

```css
.test-test {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  border-left: 3px solid;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, pink 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 100% 3px, 3px 100%;
  background-position: 0px 0px, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.test-test:before {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  content: '';
  background: transparent;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border-left: white 3px solid;
  border-bottom: green 3px solid;
}

p {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="test-test">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit
    in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Doubtful this can be achieved simply with CSS. A clip path might be a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this clip-path maker. https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ Hope it helps.

As for the roundend corners you could try "border-radius: 10px;" on the ".test-test" class.

Comment: This worked, seems like a useful tool, but I cant get the border radius working on the "cut out" section

Comment: maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765345/how-to-round-out-corners-when-using-css-clip-path