# How to add rounded effect to corners of clipped image

Tags: css

I have the image below. How can I add rounded corner to a polygon image clip like this?

```css
img {
  max-width: 400px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 0, 89% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/500/400/nature">
```

[image]

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504085/8620333

Comment: Behseini: I often make edits to your posts to improve the language a bit. Specifically, it always sounds like you are begging for someone else to take action, rather than to ask how you can do it. I wonder if you are trapped by **learned helplessness**, which may explain why you do not show any effort in your posts, or why you do not search for possible duplicates prior to posting.