# How can i Build this div with clipPath?

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I try to build the form of the div with the gradient. The one where the corner in the top left is gone. But I don't know how I can do that with the clipPath function. Does anyone know how to do that?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAwuX.png)

This is my Div and i need to cut the top left corner like the picture describes

```html
<div className="rounded-lg rounded-tl-none border">
  <p>{title}</p>
  <p>{content}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts with [clip path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) at all yet? Please show what you've tried

Comment: Maybe try a [generator](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: Also see this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765345/how-to-round-out-corners-when-using-css-clip-path