# Can you put border-radius in octagon?

Tags: html, css, clip-path, border-radius

How to put a border-radius in an octagon shape

```
clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
```

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765345/how-to-round-out-corners-when-using-css-clip-path