# How do I draw a bottom-right triangle with a curved border?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, shapes

As stated on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/), a CSS triangle can be written as:

```css
#triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

Curving the border via CSS however, doesn't seem to work:

```css
#triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

It creates glitches on FF, and shows the whole triangle as red on Chrome. Safari seems the only one to show what I would expect.

---

Question 1. Is this a browser bug or am I doing something wrong?

Question 2. Any other way to easily implement a bottom-right triangle with a bottom-right border-radius? I'm thinking SVG, but then the curvature poignancy will be kind of difficult to modify from code.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this example- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446677/how-to-make-3-corner-rounded-triangle-in-css

Answer (score 2):

Case-1: Same in Chrome , Firefox , IE

```
 border-bottom:  100px solid red;
 border-left:  100px solid yellow;
 border-right: 100px solid green;
 border-top : 100px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
```

In Chrome , Firefox , IE
[image]

Case-2: Same in Chrome , Firefox, IE
   If `border-top` not provided its considered as `border-top:none`

```
      border-bottom:  100px solid red;
      border-left:  100px solid yellow;
      border-right: 100px solid green;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
```

In Chrome , Firefox , IE
[image]

 
Case 3:   Same in Chrome and IE , Different in Firefox
Here `border-top:none;border-right:none;`

```
      border-left:  100px solid yellow;    
      border-bottom:  100px solid red;      
      border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
```

Chrome , IE
 [image]

Firefox
 [image]

Case-4:Different in IE , Different in Chrome, Different in Firefox
Here `border-top:none;border-right:none;`

```
      border-left:  100px solid transparent;    
      border-bottom:  100px solid red;      
      border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
```

In Chrome
[image]

In Firefox
[image]

In IE
[image]

Case-5: Same in Chrome , Firefox , IE
Here `border-top:none;border-right:none;border-bottom-right-radius:none`

```
      border-left:  100px solid transparent;    
      border-bottom:  100px solid red;
```

In Chrome , Firefox , IE
[image]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdRZNz)

```css
#triangle {
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border: 100px solid red;
          border-left: 100px solid transparent;
          border-top: 100px solid transparent;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: yep! That's it! Will you add an explanation of why your snippet works and my doesn't so that I can accept this answer?

Comment: @doplumi Updated post , wherever it shows inconsistent behaviour, it can be considered as bug or just different implementations of css modules in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of an SVG solution best, but you could do something like this with pure CSS if you have a fixed background color to place it on. I'm using pseudo elements, but the idea is to place one triangle on top of another to 'mask' it, which can probably be done in other ways too:

https://codepen.io/alexmacarthur/pen/dWOoYL

```
Original Triangle:
<div id="triangle"></div>
<br>
Possible Solution:
<div id="triangle2"></div>

<style>
#triangle {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-bottom: 100px solid red;
   border-left: 100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 }

 #triangle2 {
   position: relative;

   &:before,
   &:after {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-top: 100px solid white;
     border-right: 100px solid transparent;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
   }

   &:after {
     z-index: 0;
     border-right: none;
     border-top: none;
     border-bottom: 100px solid red;
     border-left: 100px solid transparent;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
   }
 }
 </style>
```