# css rounded corner of right angled triangle

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am creating a small stylised triangular motif 'before' my h1 element, but I am not able to get the corners rounded correctly. The top right is fine but the other two has this clipping issue.

Here is the output along with a blown up image of the shape:

[image]

The code used is below:

```css
h1:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.7em;
  height: 0.7em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 0%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 0%);
  background-color:  #34495e;
  border-radius: 0.12em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

I would like all corners to be smoothly rounded without any sharp corners. Perhaps there is a better way to do this. Any other tips to improve this are also welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to get it so that each corner in the triangle is rounded? Do you have to do this in CSS? SVG might be simpler

Comment: That's my backup plan. But, it would be great if I could just get it done in CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make 3-corner-rounded triangle in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446677/how-to-make-3-corner-rounded-triangle-in-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea where you can rely on 2 pseudo element and some background coloration to approximate it. You simply need to find the correct value to have the perfect overlap between both pseudo elements.

```css
h1 {
  padding-left:1em;
  position:relative;
}

h1:before {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(50% - 0.35em);
  width: 0.7em;
  height: 0.7em;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #34495e 50%, transparent 50%);
  border-radius: 0.1em;
}
h1:after {
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 3.8px;
    top: -0.1px;
    width: 0.92em;
    height: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top,#34495e 3.5px,transparent 5px);
    border-radius: 0.1em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are rounding the whole node. Apply `border-radius` only to the top-right corner

```css
h1:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.7em;
  height: 0.7em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 0%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 0%);
  background-color:  #34495e;
  border-radius: 0 0.12em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

Comment: Ok So i wasn't very clear with my question. My aim to keep all corners rounded. I would like the top-left and bottom-right to be smoothly rounded similar to the top-right.

Comment: @rmf i do not think there is a direct way (*like a specific value*) to do it. You could use an svg for the clip-path or you could define a much more detailed polygon which approximates the curve you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional styling to each individual corner in your CSS by adding:

```
border-radius: 0.4em 0.1em 0.4em 0.1em
```

You can change these numbers to suit what you need. The first and the third (the ones I've added 0.4em next to) control the corners that you are looking for I believe.

Comment: It doesn't matter what value I round the corners with, the polygon is still going to clip it making it look weird. With a smaller value, I suppose it will be slightly less noticeable.

Comment: Ah I understand, I think I would go down the SVG route in that case

Answer (score 0):

Aside from SVG or manually constructing the curves in the `clip-path`, you could add an `:after` element to act as the curved hypotenuse. This has a lot of magic numbers in it to get sizing and placement right, so I'm not sure how scalable it is, but it at least gets you there with CSS in this one situation.

```css
h1 {
position: relative;
}

h1:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.7em;
  height: 0.7em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 0%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 0%);
  background-color:  #34495e;
  border-radius: 0.12em;
}

h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: .24em;
  top: .123em;
  
  width: 0.2em;
  height: 0.87em;
  background-color:  #34495e;
  border-radius: 0.12em;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
```